# Call to undefined method Phpword::addSection() in phpword

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpword

I recently started using the PHPWord library with my Codeigniter project.
When I tried to create a table using one of the suggestion from Stackoverflow - I am getting Fatal error: Call to undefined method Phpword::addSection() .

Below is my code from Controller :

```
        $this->load->library('Phpword');
$document_with_table = new PhpWord();
        $section = $document_with_table->addSection();
        $table = $section->addTable();
        for ($r = 1; $r <= 8; $r++) {
            $table->addRow();
            for ($c = 1; $c <= 5; $c++) {
                $table->addCell(1750)->addText("Row {$r}, Cell {$c}");
            }
        }

// Create writer to convert document to xml
        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($document_with_table, 'Word2007');

// Get all document xml code
        $fullxml = $objWriter->getWriterPart('Document')->write();

// Get only table xml code
        $tablexml = preg_replace('/^[\s\S]*(<w:tbl\b.*<\/w:tbl>).*/', '$1', $fullxml);

//Open template with ${table}
        $template_document = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('C:\xampp\htdocs\practice_ci\CodeIgniter\template.docx');

// Replace mark by xml code of table
        $template_document->setValue('table', $tablexml);

//save template with table
        $template_document->saveAs('template_with_table.docx');
```

Comment: Which version of the library are you using? Perhaps it's an old one that didn't have the method yet.

Comment: I am using this one - https://github.com/webeasystep/phpword_codeigniter
it is integrated with Codeigniter and not having any other Versions.

Comment: I replaced library files from this with latest version of PHPWord - but still no luck